# Removing a vertex from Matlab's isosurface

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, point-clouds

I have an isosurface  data in MATLAB. For example:

```
[x,y,z,v] = flow;
FV = isosurface(x,y,z,v);

FV = 

vertices: [4208x3 double]
   faces: [8192x3 double]
```

I also have a list of vertices indexes which I would like to remove:

```
 verticesToRemove = [1183, 1852, 2219, 1925, 3684];
```

How can I remove these set of vertices from the mesh and update the faces list accordingly? 
I would like the topological structure of the mesh to remain the same (i.e. the deleted faces needs to be replaced by faces which don't go through deleted vertices).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do (if you just want to display the mesh) is to simply set their value to `NaN`, then you won't have to update your `Faces` matrix and all faces which use these vertices will be ignored during rendering.

```
FV.vertices(verticesToRemove,:) = NaN;
```

If you actually want to update the structure to be used elsewhere, you can recompute the faces. After you remove the vertices.

```
% Remove the vertex values at the specified index values
newVertices = FV.vertices;
newVertices(verticesToRemove,:) = [];

% Find the new index for each of the new vertices
[~, newVertexIndex] = ismember(FV.vertices, newVertices, 'rows');

% Find any faces that used the vertices that we removed and remove them
newFaces = FV.faces(all(FV.faces ~= verticesToRemove, 2),:);

% Now update the vertex indices to the new ones
newFaces = newVertexIndex(newFaces);

FV.vertices = newVertices;
FV.faces = newFaces;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There is another issue that I wasn't clear about before (I updated my question accordingly): I would like the topology of the structure to remain the same (i.e. I don't want to create holes in the mesh due to the vertex removal). Do you know how can I fill the created hole?

Comment: @drorco As far as I know, that is a pretty ill-posed problem. You would likely need to remove the point and re-mesh your data.

Comment: and how can I remash the data? is there a function for it?

Comment: @drorco There is no guaranteed built-in way to do this especially since it's an isovolume.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the above solution but still wanted to clean the `nan` values from my faces and vertices to save some memory & time down the road:

```
for i = length(FV.vertices):-1:1
    if any(isnan(FV.vertices(i,:)))
        FV.faces(any(FV.faces==i,2), :) = []; % remove faces
        FV.vertices(i,:) = []; % remove vertices
        FV.faces(FV.faces>i) = FV.faces(FV.faces>i)-1; % slide indices
    end
end
```